# Date Picker not loaded after a function called in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, cakephp-2.0

I have a form ,in that there have a text box which can take date from datepicker.

Then there have a `add more` link,which create a new text box which is also a datepicker textbox.

But it doesnot load the datepicker.

This is my code:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery.min.js');?>
<?php echo $this->Html->script('popup.js');?>
<?php echo $this->Html->css('forms'); ?>
<?php echo $this->html->script(array('scripts')); ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo HTTP_HOST;?>app/webroot/js/datepick/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="<?php echo HTTP_HOST;?>app/webroot/js/datepick/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo HTTP_HOST;?>app/webroot/js/datepick/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo HTTP_HOST;?>app/webroot/js/datepick/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo HTTP_HOST;?>app/webroot/js/datepick/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo HTTP_HOST;?>app/webroot/js/datepick/themes/demos.css">
    <script>
    $(function() {
        var dsr_counter = $("#dsr_counter").val();
        for(i=1;i<=dsr_counter;i++){
            $("#converterdiv"+dsr_counter).css("display","none");
        }

        $( "#meeting_date1" ).datepicker();
        $( "#format" ).change(function() {
            $( "#meeting_date1" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", $( this ).val() );
        });

        $( "#dsr_date1" ).datepicker();
        $( "#format" ).change(function() {
            $( "#dsr_date1" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", $( this ).val() );
        });

        for(i=1;i<=dsr_counter;i++){

            $("input:radio[name=action_converter"+dsr_counter+"]").click(function() {
                var value = $(this).val();
                if (value=="yes") {
                    $("#converter_yes"+dsr_counter).css("display","block");
                    $("#converter_no"+dsr_counter).css("display","none");
                    $("#converted"+dsr_counter).val("yes");
                } else {
                    $("#converter_yes"+dsr_counter).css("display","none");
                    $("#converter_no"+dsr_counter).css("display","block");
                    $("#converted"+dsr_counter).val("no");
                } 
            });
        }
    });
    function add_dsr(num,width){
        new_num = parseInt(num)+parseInt(1);
        add_more_dsr(num,width);
        $('#meeting_date'+new_num ).datepicker();
        $( "#format" ).change(function() {
            $( "#meeting_date"+new_num ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", $( this ).val() );
        });
    }
    </script>

    <div id="popup_mm" style="display:block; margin-left:10px; margin-top:10px; float:left;">

            <?php echo $this->Form->create('TravancoDSR', array('class'=>'form'));?>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-left:150px; width:80%; border:1px solid #CCCCCC;">
              <tr>
                <td><div class="dsr_input_div">
                    <?php
                        echo $this->Form->input('title1',       array(  'div'=>'frm_filed_new',
                                                                        'error' => array(   'wrap' => 'div',
                                                                                            'class' => 'formerror'
                                                                                        ),
                                                                        'label' => 'Title',
                                                                    ));
                        echo $this->Form->input('name1',        array(  'div'=>'frm_filed_new',
                                                                        'error' => array(   'wrap' => 'div',
                                                                                            'class' => 'formerror'
                                                                                        ),
                                                                        'label' => 'Name',
                                                                    ));
                        echo $this->Form->input('address1',array(   'div'=>'frm_filed_new',
                                                                        'error' => array(   'wrap' => 'div',
                                                                                            'class' => 'formerror'
                                                                                        ),
                                                                        'label' => 'Address',
                                                                        'type' => 'textarea',
                                                                            'cols'=>60,
                                                                            'rows' => 5,
                                                                    ));
                        echo $this->Form->input('phone1',       array(  'div'=>'frm_filed_new',
                                                                        'error' => array(   'wrap' => 'div',
                                                                                            'class' => 'formerror'
                                                                                        ),
                                                                        'label' => 'Phone',
                                                                    ));
                        ?>
                </div></td>
                <td><div class="dsr_input_div">
                    <?php
                    echo $this->Form->input('business_name1',       array(  'div'=>'frm_filed_new',
                                                                        'error' => array(   'wrap' => 'div',
                                                                                            'class' => 'formerror'
                                                                                        ),
                                                                        'label' => 'Name Of Business',
                                                                    ));
                    echo $this->Form->input('business_address1',array(  'div'=>'frm_filed_new',
                                                                        'error' => array(   'wrap' => 'div',
                                                                                            'class' => 'formerror'
                                                                                        ),
                                                                        'label' => 'Business Address',
                                                                        'type' => 'textarea',
                                                                            'cols'=>60,
                                                                            'rows' => 5,
                                                                    ));
                    echo $this->Form->input('status1',      array(  'options' => array(     'Suspect' => 'Suspect', 
                                                                                        'Prospect' => 'Prospect', 
                                                                                        'Lead' => 'Lead',
                                                                                        'Converter' => 'Converter'
                                                                                      ), 
                                                                    'empty' => '(choose one)',
                                                                    'div'=>'formfield',
                                                                    'error' => array(   'wrap' => 'div',
                                                                                        'class' => 'formerror'
                                                                                    ),
                                                                    'style'=>'width:13em',
                                                                    'label'=>'Status'
                                                            ));
                    echo $this->Form->input('meeting_date1',        array(  'div'=>'frm_filed_new',
                                                                        'error' => array(   'wrap' => 'div',
                                                                                            'class' => 'formerror'
                                                                                        ),
                                                                        'label' => 'Date of Meeting',
                                                                        'id'=>'meeting_date1',
                                                                        'value'=>'',
                                                                    )); 

                    ?>
                </div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="background-color:#F4F4F4;">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div class="converter_div" style="margin-left:58px;"> 
                            <input type="checkbox" name="data[TravancoDSR][chkconverted1]" id="chkconverted1" class="converter_chk" onClick="return show_converter(1);"  />If Converted 
                        </div>
                    <div style="float:left; color:#C2A34F; margin-left:80px;" id="converterdiv1">
                        <input type="radio" name="action_converter1" id="action_converter_yes1" value="yes" style="float:none;" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Yes
                        <input type="radio" name="action_converter1" id="action_converter_no1" value="no" style="float:none; margin-left:30px;" />&nbsp;&nbsp;No
                        <?php                       
                            echo $this->Form->input('converted1',       array(  'div'=>'frm_filed_new',
                                                                            'error' => array(   'wrap' => 'div',
                                                                                                'class' => 'formerror'
                                                                                            ),
                                                                            'label' => 'Date of Conversion',
                                                                            'id'=>'converted1',
                                                                            'type'=>'hidden',
                                                                        )); 

                        ?>

                    </div>
                    <div class="converterdiv" id="converter_yes1" style="display:none;">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:0px;">
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                    <div class="dsr_input_div">
                        <?php

                            echo $this->Form->input('dsr_date1',        array(  'div'=>'frm_filed_new',
                                                                            'error' => array(   'wrap' => 'div',
                                                                                                'class' => 'formerror'
                                                                                            ),
                                                                            'label' => 'Date of Conversion',
                                                                            'id'=>'dsr_date1',
                                                                            'value'=>'',
                                                                        )); 

                        ?>

                    </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <div class="dsr_input_div">
                        <?php
                            echo $this->Form->input('comments1',    array(  'type' => 'textarea',
                                                                            'cols'=>60,
                                                                            'rows' => 5,
                                                                            'div'=>'frm_filed_new',
                                                                            'error' => array(   'wrap' => 'div',
                                                                                                'class' => 'formerror'
                                                                                        ),
                                                                            'label' => 'Comments',
                                                                            'id'=>'comments1'
                                                                    ));
                            ?>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="converterdiv" id="converter_no1" style="display:none;">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:0px;">
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                    <div class="dsr_input_div">
                        <?php

                            echo $this->Form->input('reason1',          array(  'type' => 'textarea',
                                                                            'cols'=>60,
                                                                            'rows' => 5,
                                                                            'div'=>'frm_filed_new',
                                                                            'error' => array(   'wrap' => 'div',
                                                                                                'class' => 'formerror'
                                                                                            ),
                                                                            'label' => 'If Not Reason',
                                                                            'id'=>'reason1',
                                                                            'value'=>'',
                                                                        )); 

                            echo $this->Form->input('reference0',   array(  'type' => 'text',
                                                                            'div'=>'frm_filed_new',
                                                                            'error' => array(   'wrap' => 'div',
                                                                                                'class' => 'formerror'
                                                                                        ),
                                                                            'label' => 'Reference',
                                                                            'id'=>'reference0'
                                                                    ));
                            ?>
                            <div id="add_more_div1" style="padding:0em;">
                            </div>
                            <div style="margin-left:150px;">
                                <a  style="cursor:pointer;"onclick="return add_more(1);">Add More</a>
                                <input name="data[TravancoDSR][counter1]" id="counter1" value="1" type="hidden" />
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <div class="dsr_input_div">
                        <?php
                            echo $this->Form->input('action1',  array(  'type' => 'textarea',
                                                                            'cols'=>60,
                                                                            'rows' => 5,
                                                                            'div'=>'frm_filed_new',
                                                                            'error' => array(   'wrap' => 'div',
                                                                                                'class' => 'formerror'
                                                                                        ),
                                                                            'label' => 'Action Taken',
                                                                    ));
                            ?>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td align="center" colspan="2">

              </td>
              </tr>
            </table>

            <div id="add_more_dsr_1" style="display:none;"></div>
            <div style="margin-left:220px;" id="dsr_more_link_1">
            <?php $cnt = 1; ?>
                <a  style="cursor:pointer;"onclick="return add_dsr(<?php echo $cnt?>,150);">Add More</a>
                <input name="data[TravancoDSR][dsr_counter]" id="dsr_counter" value="<?php echo $cnt?>" type="hidden" />
            </div>
            <?php 
                echo $this->Form->input('emp_id',       array(  'div'=>'frm_filed_new',
                                                                        'value'=>$employee_id,
                                                                        'error' => array(   'wrap' => 'div',
                                                                                            'class' => 'formerror'
                                                                                        ),
                                                                        'label' => 'empid',
                                                                        'type'=>'hidden'
                                                                    )); 
                echo $this->Form->input('dsr_created_date',     array(      'div'=>'frm_filed_new',
                                                                            'error' => array(   'wrap' => 'div',
                                                                                                'class' => 'formerror'
                                                                                        ),
                                                                            'label' => false,
                                                                            'type'=>'hidden',
                                                                            'value'=>date ('Y-m-d')
                                                                    ));
                $frmid = "'TravancoDSRMarketingAddDSRForm'";
                echo $this->Form->button('Save DSR', array('type'=>'submit','class'=>'submitclass','onClick'=>'return dsr_adding('.$frmid.')','style'=>'width: 95px; height: 25px; margin-left: 225px; float:left; margin-top:0;')); ?>

            <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>

            </div>
```

This is the `add_more_dsr()` that is in `scripts.js` file

```
function add_more_dsr(num,width){
        width = parseInt(width)-6;
        new_num=parseInt(num)+parseInt(1);
        document.getElementById("dsr_counter").value=new_num;

        var fields = "";

        fields+="<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" border=\"0\" style=\"margin-left:"+width+"px; width:80%; border:1px solid #CCCCCC;\">";
        fields+="<tbody><tr><td><div class=\"dsr_input_div\"><div class=\"frm_filed_new\">";
        fields+="<label for=\"TravancoDSRTitle"+new_num+"\">Title</label>";
        fields+="<input type=\"text\" id=\"TravancoDSRTitle"+new_num+"\" maxlength=\"50\" name=\"data[TravancoDSR][title"+new_num+"]\">";
        fields+="</div><div class=\"frm_filed_new\"><label for=\"TravancoDSRName"+new_num+"\">Name</label>";
        fields+="<input type=\"text\" id=\"TravancoDSRName"+new_num+"\" maxlength=\"50\" name=\"data[TravancoDSR][name"+new_num+"]\">";
        fields+="</div><div class=\"frm_filed_new\"><label for=\"TravancoDSRAddress"+new_num+"\">Address</label>";
        fields+="<textarea id=\"TravancoDSRAddress"+new_num+"\" rows=\"5\" cols=\"60\" name=\"data[TravancoDSR][address"+new_num+"]\"></textarea>";
        fields+="</div><div class=\"frm_filed_new\"><label for=\"TravancoDSRPhone"+new_num+"\">Phone</label>";
        fields+="<input type=\"text\" id=\"TravancoDSRPhone"+new_num+"\" maxlength=\"30\" name=\"data[TravancoDSR][phone"+new_num+"]\">";
        fields+="</div></div></td><td><div class=\"dsr_input_div\"><div class=\"frm_filed_new\">";
        fields+="<label for=\"TravancoDSRBusinessName"+new_num+"\">Name Of Business</label>";
        fields+="<input type=\"text\" id=\"TravancoDSRBusinessName"+new_num+"\" maxlength=\"30\" name=\"data[TravancoDSR][business_name"+new_num+"]\">";
        fields+="</div><div class=\"frm_filed_new\"><label for=\"TravancoDSRBusinessAddress"+new_num+"\">Business Address</label>";
        fields+="<textarea id=\"TravancoDSRBusinessAddress"+new_num+"\" rows=\"5\" cols=\"60\" name=\"data[TravancoDSR][business_address"+new_num+"]\"></textarea>";
        fields+="</div><div class=\"formfield\"><label for=\"TravancoDSRStatus"+new_num+"\">Status</label>";
        fields+="<select id=\"TravancoDSRStatus"+new_num+"\" style=\"width:13em\" name=\"data[TravancoDSR][status"+new_num+"]\">";
        fields+="<option value=\"\">(choose one)</option><option value=\"Suspect\">Suspect</option>";
        fields+="<option value=\"Prospect\">Prospect</option><option value=\"Lead\">Lead</option>";
        fields+="<option value=\"Converter\">Converter</option></select>";
        fields+="</div><div class=\"frm_filed_new\"><label for=\"meeting_date"+new_num+"\">Date of Meeting</label>";
        fields+="<input type=\"text\" value=\"\" id=\"meeting_date"+new_num+"\" name=\"data[TravancoDSR][meeting_date"+new_num+"]\" class=\"hasDatepicker\">";
        fields+="</div>";
        fields+="</div></td></tr><tr style=\"background-color:#F4F4F4;\"><td colspan=\"2\">";
        fields+="<div style=\"margin-left:58px;\" class=\"converter_div\"> ";
        fields+="<input type=\"checkbox\" onclick=\"return show_converter("+new_num+");\" class=\"converter_chk\" id=\"chkconverted"+new_num+"\" name=\"data[TravancoDSR][chkconverted"+new_num+"]\">";
        fields+="If Converted</div>";
        fields+="<div id=\"converterdiv"+new_num+"\" style=\"float: left; color: rgb(194, 163, 79); margin-left: 80px; display: none;\">";
        fields+="<input type=\"radio\" style=\"float:none;\" onclick=\"return show_radio(this.value,"+new_num+")\" value=\"yes\" id=\"action_converter_yes"+new_num+"\" name=\"action_converter"+new_num+"\">&nbsp;&nbsp;Yes";
        fields+="<input type=\"radio\"  onclick=\"return show_radio(this.value,"+new_num+")\"style=\"float:none; margin-left:30px;\" value=\"no\" id=\"action_converter_no"+new_num+"\" name=\"action_converter"+new_num+"\">&nbsp;&nbsp;No";
        fields+="<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"converted"+new_num+"\" name=\"data[TravancoDSR][converted"+new_num+"]\"></div>";
        fields+="<div style=\"display:none;\" id=\"converter_yes"+new_num+"\" class=\"converterdiv\">";
        fields+="<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" style=\"border:0px;\"><tbody><tr><td>";
        fields+="<div class=\"dsr_input_div\"><div class=\"frm_filed_new\"><label for=\"dsr_date"+new_num+"\">Date of Conversion</label>";
        fields+="<input type=\"text\" maxlength=\"30\" value=\"\" id=\"dsr_date"+new_num+"\" name=\"data[TravancoDSR][dsr_date"+new_num+"]\" class=\"hasDatepicker\">";
        fields+="</div></div></td><td><div class=\"dsr_input_div\"><div class=\"frm_filed_new\"><label for=\"comments"+new_num+"\">Comments</label>";
        fields+="<textarea id=\"comments"+new_num+"\" rows=\"5\" cols=\"60\" name=\"data[TravancoDSR][comments"+new_num+"]\"></textarea>";
        fields+="</div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div>";
        fields+="<div style=\"display:none;\" id=\"converter_no"+new_num+"\" class=\"converterdiv\">";
        fields+="<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" style=\"border:0px;\">";
        fields+="<tbody><tr><td><div class=\"dsr_input_div\"><div class=\"frm_filed_new\"><label for=\"reason"+new_num+"\">If Not Reason</label>";
        fields+="<textarea id=\"reason"+new_num+"\" rows=\"5\" cols=\"60\" name=\"data[TravancoDSR][reason"+new_num+"]\"></textarea>";

        fields+="</div><div class=\"frm_filed_new\"><label for=\"reference0\">Reference</label>";
        fields+="<input type=\"text\" id=\"reference0\" name=\"data[TravancoDSR][reference0]\">";

        fields+="</div><div style=\"padding:0em;\" id=\"add_more_div"+new_num+"\"></div><div style=\"margin-left:150px;\">";
        fields+="<a onclick=\"return add_more("+new_num+");\" style=\"cursor:pointer;\">Add More</a>";
        fields+="<input type=\"hidden\" value=\""+new_num+"\" id=\"counter"+new_num+"\" name=\"data[TravancoDSR][counter"+new_num+"]\"></div></div></td>";
        fields+="<td><div class=\"dsr_input_div\"><div class=\"frm_filed_new\"><label for=\"TravancoDSRAction"+new_num+"\">Action Taken</label>";
        fields+="<textarea id=\"TravancoDSRAction"+new_num+"\" rows=\"5\" cols=\"60\" name=\"data[TravancoDSR][action"+new_num+"]\"></textarea>";
        fields+="</div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr><tr><td align=\"center\" colspan=\"2\">";
        fields+="</td></tr></tbody></table>";
        fields+="<div style=\"margin-left:220px;\" id=\"dsr_more_link_"+new_num+"\">";
        fields+="<a  style=\"cursor:pointer;\" onclick=\"return add_more_dsr("+new_num+","+width+");\">Add More</a></div>";
        fields+="<div id=\"add_more_dsr_"+new_num+"\" style=\"display:none;\"></div>";
        document.getElementById('add_more_dsr_'+num).style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("add_more_dsr_"+num).innerHTML=fields;
        document.getElementById('dsr_more_link_'+num).style.display="none";

    }
```

How can i do this?
When click `add_more` it creates a new table with a new date textbox but i cant to take date from that textbox .

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything in

```
$(function(){ ... });
```

only gets executed on page load.

In your add_more_dsr, you will need to apply the datepicker to the new element

EDIT:
Try like this at the end of your add_more_dsr (after the textbox is added to the dom)

```
$('#meeting_date'+new_num ).datepicker();
    $( "#format" ).change(function() {
        $( "#dsr_date1" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", $( this ).val() );
    });
```

**EDIT 2**

The problem is that when you do:

```
document.getElementById("add_more_dsr_"+num).innerHTML=fields;
```

It just keeps replacing the existing contents.

Also, instead on inline javascript like this:

```
<a  style="cursor:pointer;"onclick="return add_more_dsr(1);">Add More</a>
```

Try assigning an onlick event handler with jquery:

```
$('#linkAddMore').on('click', function() {

    add_more_dsr(num);
    num++;
});
```

Take a look at the [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/4D4T5/3/).  It adds new text boxes, but JSFIDDLE won't load the UI library, so you will have to test the datepicker if it works in your own code

Comment: after you create any new element and add it to the dom, you need to call the datepicker function on that element like in my first example

Comment: in `add_dsr` function i called `add_more_dsr` in this the innerhtml is wrote after that in `add_dsr` i already put the code for datepicker also,But nothing happen.............

Answer (score 0):

The requirement can be done . Looks like its a problem with the ID's.

**ID's** have to be **unique** on the HTML page..

Because You have duplicate id's on the page the event handler for change seems to be overwriting the previously declared event...

Also because you are creating the elements on the click of the anchor, when the datepicker is associated the element is still not present in your DOM..

So you need to add the datepicker as soon as the element is created..